# Unable to inspect the ios app using appium inspector

Tags: ios, appium, inspector

1. I am using appium version 1.3.7 version.
2. After starting appium sever, the app get installed in ios simulator.
3. When I tried to inspect using appium inspector, the refresh button in the appium inspector keeps on loading, it doesn't load the home page of an app at all.

Comment: was tha app openes on the simulator when you are inspecting ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to update your appium, since new appium version support XCUITest you might be ended to some changes in locators and other setup. This is my suggestion because you need to automate your cases on iOS 10, so in that cases you forced to upgrade the appium.

Coming to your question, if you are not able to access the appium inspector there is workaround.

How to inspect ios elements ,

Option one : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=254nbRjjQjc

Option two : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BgkVp0v3BM

For more videos :

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCaJA59vxBDS7smS81Gqf7KA

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows or Mac machine? I would suggest to use ~/android-sdk/tools/uiautomatorviewer. This will open one window, you can take screenshot of current screen from connected device and from left pane elements can be inspected.

Comment: Trying to work on ios app.uiautomatorviewer won't work.